# A required class was missing while executing org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905:run: javax/ws/rs/client/RxInvokerProvider

Tags: java, maven, jetty, pom.xml

I keep on getting this error message:

> A required class was missing while executing org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905:run: javax/ws/rs/client/RxInvokerProvider

I have tried to remove the maven repo so that it is forced to download the library again, but with no result. If I manually add this dependency it complains on another thing and so on which makes me think it is something else that causes this.

Anyone have any clue? here is my pom.xml as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>se.hrmsoftware.hrm</groupId>
        <artifactId>sleepy-oyster-projects</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<artifactId>sleepy-common-ws</artifactId>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>se.hrmsoftware.hrm</groupId>
        <artifactId>sleepy-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
</project>
```

Also this project have been working but now it won't start it anymore.

Here is the maven dependency tree:

```
    se.hrmsoftware.hrm:sleepy-common-ws:war:1.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] \- se.hrmsoftware.hrm:sleepy-commons:jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO]    +- net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:6.2.2.jre8:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.17:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.10:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:7.5.5:compile
[INFO]       +- com.vaadin:vaadin-sass-compiler:jar:0.9.12:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]       |  \- com.vaadin.external.flute:flute:jar:1.3.0.gg2:compile
[INFO]       +- com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:jar:7.5.5:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.vaadin.external.streamhtmlparser:streamhtmlparser-jsilver:jar:0.0.10.vaadin1:compile
[INFO]       |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:guava:jar:16.0.1.vaadin1:compile
[INFO]       \- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.1:compile
```

Comment: What does your `mvn dependency:tree` look like for this problematic project?

Comment: Use Java 8 instead of Java 9 for now.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt i added the tree.

Comment: It were the Jersey version wich i guess @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen were pointing at that made it crash going down to 2.17 fixed it!

Comment: Noticed the `javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile` in your tree. Since you are using Jetty 9, you have Servlet 3.1 available to you.  You can update the version of that dependency if you want (not required, as Jetty is backward compat to older versions of the servlet spec).  Since you are a `war`, at a minimum you will want to set that dependency to `<scope>provided</scope>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javax.ws.rs.client.RxInvokerProvider` was introduced in JAX RS API 2.1

Yet your dependency tree has ...

```
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
```

You have a bad dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you encounter "Also this project have been working but now it wont start it anymore." you need to figure out what was changed when the project broke.  In order to do so, you need source control (like git, mercurial or bazaar).   Check out commits until you find the one where it worked before the commit and not after.  Then look into what was changed.

If you use git, then `git bisect` may be helpful.  See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#_binary_search for how to do this.

If you don't use source control, now is a good time to reconsider.